# Set of smooth points in an ind-variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ind-schemes

There is a remark (Remark IV.4.3.2) in Shrawan Kumar's book* that says it is unknown to the author that the set of smooth points of an ind-variety is open.

I was wondering if this has been answered yet?
It would be great if you could mention some relevant references as well.

Cheers!

*:Kac-Moody Groups, their Flag varieties and Representation Theory(2002)

Comment: Since this is affirmative for any variety and ind-varieties are direct limits of varieties, I think we only need to show that the set of smooth points of ind-varieties equals the direct limit of the smooth points of its directed system of varieties. Am I right?